# How to reuse drawable

Tags: android, xml

I have a number of background drawables that the only different is the color of the border or the color of the background.

Is there a way to define a general drawable and then add (or change) the attribute I need.

For example here is a rectangular drawable

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/radius_small"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/simple_black" />
    <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="@color/simple_white" />
    <padding
        android:left="@dimen/two_dp"
        android:right="@dimen/two_dp"/>
</shape>
```

and I would like to change the solid color or the stroke color, and not to create a separate drawable for each one.

Comment: What's the minimum target SDK version for your app?

Comment: The minimum API is 9

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that you want to do it programatically. If all you need is to change the background and/or stroke color, here is how you can do it:

1. Obtain a reference to the shape

   ```
    GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_id)
   ```
2. To change color

   ```
    drawable.setColor(Color.RED)
   ```
3. To change stroke color and width (notice that you can only change both of them together, so I recommend keeping a variable with the stroke's width in px)

   `drawable.setStroke(Util.dpToPx(context, 2), Color.YELLOW)`

Comment: Thanks @Ari, but I want to do it in XML. However, if I do not find a satisfactory solution in XML I might use your solution.

Comment: You are welcome. If you do decide to use my answer, please mark it.

Comment: In any case, it is not clear to me how do I get a reference to the shape, when I am using the drawable as a background of a LinearLayout. I tried your code replacing shape_id with the name of mydrawable, and  I changed the color and the stroke but no change took place..

Comment: You can get a reference to it using (GradientDrawable)yourView.getDrawable() and then change the color.

Comment: I figured out myself using 

  LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
  GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) layout.getBackground();. In any case I gave you your point even though I prefer an XML solution. Thanks.

Comment: Another problem with this solution is that it changes the drawable for the life of the app - the change applies to other layouts and object using that drawable. I want the change to be local to the object or view used, and not to others. It renders this solution useless if I use the same drawable twice in the same layout (for different objects) and I want the change to apply to one of them only.

Comment: You can use Drawable.mutate() before you apply changes and other drawables won't be affected. Have a look at the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()

Comment: Thanks. This solved that problem. However, I still want to have it in XML, if anyone knows a way.